# How to get if the drawing sketch is being edited? (Autodesk Inventor C++ API)

Tags: windows, visual-c++, autodesk-inventor

I need to add a drawing sketch in Inventor and edit it. However, if another sketch is already being edited, my program terminates and even try/catch does not help. I can't find a property of the sketch showing if it is being edited or not. My main part of code is here:

```
// All of these three functions pass try/catch perfectly. Program never terminates
Inventor::Application^ App = (Inventor::Application^)Marshal::GetActiveObject("Inventor.Application");
DrawingDocument^ Doc = (DrawingDocument^)App->ActiveDocument;
Sheet^ Sh = Doc->ActiveSheet;

DrawingSketch^ Sk;

try
{
    Sh->Sketches->Add();
    Sk = Sh->Sketches[Sh->Sketches->Count];
    Sk->Edit(); // Crushes the program completely if another sketch is being edited
}
catch (...)
{
    return;
}
```

I tried to cycle through all the sketches and close them all. This behaves in a way I cannot understand.

```
try
{
    // Note: in Inventor indexes definitely start from 1
    for (int i = 1; i <= Sh->Sketches->Count; i++)
    {
        Sk = Sh->Sketches[i];
        Sk->ExitEdit();
    }
}
catch (...)
{
    return;
}
```

For example, when the sketch 2 is open, the first cycle (i = 1) that tries to close the sketch 1, somehow closes the sketch 2. And the second iteration (i = 2) that now cannot close the sketch 2, as it is already closed, calls 'catch' and further 'return'.

Comment: The cycling of ExitEdit closes the active sketch and does not crush the program, so it actually can be used in this situation. Anyway, programming it like this looks at least strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with C++, but here is VBA sample how to detect the drawing sketch is in edit mode

```
Dim oDrawing As DrawingDocument
Set oDrawing = ThisApplication.ActiveDocument

Dim oSheet As Sheet
Set oSheet = oDrawing.ActiveSheet

Dim editedObject As Variant
Set editedObject = ThisApplication.ActiveEditObject

If editedObject.Type = ObjectTypeEnum.kDrawingSketchObject Then
    Dim activeEditSketch As DrawingSketch
    Set activeEditSketch = editedObject
    activeEditSketch.ExitEdit
End If

Dim oSketch As DrawingSketch
Set oSketch = oSheet.Sketches.Add()
```

I hope, you can convert this code to C++

Comment: Yes, that worked. In C++ I just added a line ```if (Sk == App->ActiveEditObject) Sk->ExitEdit();``` to my cycle. Maybe it could work just like ```DrawingSketch^ Sk = App->ActiveEditObject; if (Sk != nullptr) Sk->ExitEdit();``` but I didn't test it.

Comment: IMHO better solution is test if ActiveEditObject is DrawingSketch. Because only one DrawingSketch can be in edit mode at the same time.